# regenerate session on db callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to regnerate session on  successful validation of user credentials.But the session doesn't get regenerated when the code is in db callback

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){

var userName=req.body.userid.toLowerCase();
db.collection('credentials').findOne({'userName':userName},function(err,result){
    req.session.regenerate(function (err) { 

    });
});
```

});

It works fine out side it

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
var userName=req.body.userid.toLowerCase();
req.session.regenerate(function (err) { 

    });
db.collection('credentials').findOne({'userName':userName},function(err,result){

});
```

});

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use the async module and implement waterfall function

Comment: Any ideas on why this is happening. Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong?.

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: There is no error. I even logged the value within the regenerate callback. But the session is not getting regnerated(The session cookie doesn't change, additional parmaters are not being stored in the session store).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mistake was on my part.The code was responding to the request right below the code i posted. Since these work in async, I guess the response was sent beofre the session was reset.

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){

var userName=req.body.userid.toLowerCase();
db.collection('credentials').findOne({'userName':userName},function(err,result){
    req.session.regenerate(function (err) { 

    });
    res.send('welcome '+result.firstName+' '+result.lastName);
});
```

});

I moved the response inside the regenarte call back and it is working now.